# Azure Synapse Error - File cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process. Using ACLs to authorize the access

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-synapse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVPwF.jpg)Need your help to find where I am exactly wrong.

**Problem Statement** - Run the following SQL in Azure Synapse:
`

```
select top 10 * from 
OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://myxyzaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/covid_12_31_2021.csv',
    format = 'csv',
    PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
    FIRSTROW = 2) as rows
```

`

**Error Encountered** - File 'https://myxyzaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/covid_12_31_2021.csv' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.

Please note -

1. The blob (csv file) actually exists in the path. I don't have permission to assign roles using IAM in the storage account. Hence I cannot assign 'Blob Contributor or Reader' role (although I was able to create the Storage account all by myself).
2. I checked the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002#query-fails-because-file-cannot-be-opened. Please see the section [Alternative to Storage Blob Data Contributor role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002#alternative-to-storage-blob-data-contributor-role)

My understanding is, even if one is unable to grant authorization via storage account IAM, one can still let synapse access the required file using proper ACL assigment.

3. My blob path is myxyzaccount/data/covid_12_31_2021.csv
   I added the MSI of Azure Synapse in the Container Root directory (data) and gave 'Execute' permission. Then I provided Read & Execute (as well as write) permission at the file (covid_12_31_2021.csv) level.

Yet, I am getting the same error, I pasted above. For your reference I am attaching screenshots of the ACL assignments at the container (root) and file level.

Can you please help what exactly I am doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: since I am new to this community, I am not allowed to paste the screenshot of the ACLs, but I hope the description in my Notes area should be able to clarify any question related to the ACL.

Answer (score -1):

In Synapse if the query fails with the error - `File cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process` but the file actually exists, it means serverless SQL pool can't access the file. This problem usually happens because the Azure Active Directory identity doesn't have rights to access the file. By default, serverless SQL pool is trying to access the file using your Azure Active Directory identity. To resolve this issue, you need to have proper rights to access the file. First grant yourself 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the storage account you're trying to query.

Refer Microsoft’s official document: [Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current)

I tried to repro the same and it is working fine for me.

1. Make sure your Blob/ADLS storage account is linked under `Data` Tab. If it is not Linked, click on `+` symbol in above shown image to link.

[image]

2. On the file name in container, click on `New SQL Query` and select `Select TOP 100 Rows`.

[image]

3. You will get auto generated code as shown below.

```
-- This is auto-generated code
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://<storage_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/sink/business (1).csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
            PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) AS [result]
```

This will work fine now and you will get the expected result. Refer below image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. But as I mentioned earlier in my original question that I don't have privilege to assign roles in IAM. Hence, I was using the ACL route. I have pasted the link too that was mentioned in the official MS document. Pasting it here again: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002#alternative-to-storage-blob-data-contributor-role) . I have created a new linked to point to the specific file. Regards!

Comment: Ask the Storage owner to assign the required role.

Comment: Is role assignment must for accessing storage from synapse? Can it not be done using ACL? I was under the impression, as per the MS documentation, it was indeed possible: [Alternative to Storage Blob Data Contributor role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002#alternative-to-storage-blob-data-contributor-role)

Comment: Is your Storage account Linked in Synapse?

Comment: Yes, the storage account is linked in synapse.

Comment: it should work with ACL also but I'm not what exactly is wrong. For me it is working fine. Please try to provide some more insights on the approach and configuration part.